# Geometry with Medians

Tags: geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $BC = 8$. The length of median $AD$ is 5. Let $M$ be the largest possible value of $AB^2 + AC^2$, and let $m$ be the smallest possible value. Find $M - m$.

How should I go about tackling this problem? Hints and Solutions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Geometry with medians]Since the cosine of an angle and its supplement are equal but opposite in sign, then applying the cosine law$$AB^2=4^2+5^2-2BD\cdot AD\cdot cos\angle ADB$$and$$AC^2=4^2+5^2-2 CD\cdot AD\cdot cos\angle (\pi-ADB)=4^2+5^2+2CD\cdot AD\cdot cos\angle ADB$$Then since $BD=CD$, adding the two equations the last terms on the right cancel and$$AB^2+AC^2=2\times(4^2+5^2)=82$$for every pair of supplementary angles $ADB$ and $ADC$.

$AB^2+AC^2$ is unvarying for all positions of $A$, and$$M-m=0$$

Answer (score 0):

For the median $m_c$ we get $$m_c^2=16+c^2-8c\cos(\beta)$$ and
$$b^2=c^2+64-16c\cos(\beta)$$ we eliminate $\cos(\beta)$ then we have
$$25=4^2+c^2-\frac{1}{2}(8^2+c^2-b^2)$$
This gives $$50-32+8^2=c^2+b^2$$
For the second part we get
$$b^2+c^2\geq 2bc$$
and for $2bc$ we Can write $$2bc=\frac{b^2+c^2-8^2}{\cos(\alpha)}$$

Comment: Thank you. So how exactly do I figure out the maximum and minimum values of $b^2+c^2$?

Comment: The Maximum is given by $$50-32+8^2=c^2+b^2$$

Comment: For the Minimum you have the inequality $$(b^2+c^2)\left(1-\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}\right)\geq -\frac{8^2}{\cos(\alpha)}$$

Comment: If $$\cos(\alpha)<0$$ then we get $$b^2+c^2\geq \frac{8^2}{1-\cos(\alpha)}$$

Comment: If $\cos(\alpha)>0$ then we get $$b^2+c^2\le \frac{8^2}{1-\cos(\alpha)}$$

Comment: If $$\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ then we get $$b^2+c^2=8^2$$

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but your solution is way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Use cosine's law

$AB^2=4^2+5^2-20\cos {\angle ADB}$

$AC^2=4^2+5^2-20\cos {\angle ADC}=4^2+5^2+20\cos{\angle ADB}$

$\rightarrow AB^2+AC^2=82$

Then $M=m=82$ is constant.

Comment: You applied the cosine theorem wrong. But your answer is right. Edit it and I will accept your answer. :)